# Rename project built with Gradle

Tags: java, refactoring, gradle

I have a Java project built with Gradle that is using a package com.example.package1. I would like to change the package structure to com.example.package2 and name the corresponding directories accordingly.

Is there some refactor (Eclipse like) tool that can do that for me? Or what all files may I need to look into? e.g. build.gradle, settings.gradle.

Comment: Gradle doesn't care about the package name of your classes. Change the folder name, the package and import statements, and clean build your project.

Comment: I solved the issue, I had to rename not only the packages but also the project directories where those packages were placed. The applicable changes had to be done in the following files: .project, .classpath, build.gradle, settings.gradle. Still I would be interested if there is some automatic refactoring tool.

Comment: Java wants the declared package to match the file locations; that's not a gradle issue. Also, it may have been simpler to delete .project and .classpath and regenerate them. You are correct that you shouldn't have to edit those by hand.

Answer (score 0):

When you rename the directories in your project to fix the Gradle build, you should modify the following files where you will need to change the old directory name to the new.

- .project
- .classpath
- build.gradle
- settings.gradle